# Python Percentage Difference into excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question on python program. I would like to calculate the percentage of difference and store in another column. So the table is like this:

```
Name  | Country1 | Country2 | Percentage Difference
Food1 | 3.07     | 2.36     | Value1
Food2 | 2.40     | 2.55     | Value2
```

So when the user input the values, the values will run through the function, the return the value3. Then the value3 is supposed to be insert into placement of Value1 (Based on the table).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Food.csv')

value1 = float(sys.argv[1]) #User input 
value2 = float(sys.argv[2]) #User input

def test(): #function to calculate the formula
    value3 = float(
        (abs(value1 - value2) / ((value1 + value2)/2)*100)) #Formula to calculate difference
    value3 = round(value3,2) #Round up 2 decimal numbers
    return value3
```

So I was wondering, how can I solve it without entering the location of the column and rows?

Comment: if i understand correctly, you want to apply your function over the dataframe, but you want it (the program) to know what the numerical columns are to apply this operation?

Comment: yes, like after i had input the values through command line, i would like the program to run and store the value into the columns in the excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need the user input.It seems like you simply want to do the calculation for all rows.

Since you are already using pandas, this is a pretty straightforward task.

```
df['Percentage Difference'] = ((df['Country1'] - df['Country2']).abs() / 
                              ((df['Country1'] + df['Country2'] / 2) * 100)).round(2)
```

Keep in mind that the values in your example are too small to produce a meaningful result when rounded to 2 decimal places.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country1': [3.07, 2.40], 'Country2': [2.36, 2.55]})

df['Percentage Difference'] = ((df['Country1'] - df['Country2']).abs() /
                               ((df['Country1'] + df['Country2'] / 2) * 100))
df['rounded'] = df['Percentage Difference'].round(2)
print(df)
```

Outputs

```
   Country1  Country2  Percentage Difference  rounded
0      3.07      2.36                  0.002      0.0
1      2.40      2.55                  0.000      0.0
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any possible way where, I enter two different values then the values are stored in the excel file? For the two different, I prefer to have the user input though